# Precedence between member access from a pointer and cast

Tags: c, casting, operator-precedence

If I have

```
 typedef struct{
       int i;
 } typeB;

 typeA *p;
```

then: What is the precedence between member access from a pointer and cast?

```
 (typeB *)p->i
```

Is it actually `((typeB *)p)->i` or `(typeB *)(p->i)`?

Comment: There are all sorts of problems with your code, it's not compilable.  Do you mean `typeB` as opposed to `typeA`? Then `p` isn't a pointer, how are you casting it as such.  Third, it looks like you are trying to cast an int to a (typeB*)

Comment: The question only makes sense of `typeA` is a pointer type, but the asker has left it unspecified.

Comment: There are many ways to find out for yourself rather than post a question to SO ... for instance, you could try it and see.

Comment: @JimBalter: It is possible the asker tried, but reached an inconclusive result (the experimental code used a `typeA` that actually had an `i` member, for example). Sometimes, even if a starving man is willing to fish, he still needs to be taught how to fish.

Comment: @jxh Many extraordinarily unlikely things are *possible* ... for instance, it's possible that the OP never typed this question at all, that it's merely a result of various quantum fluctuations in the communication lines. My comment stands ... a simple google of C precedence would suffice, yielding http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html as the first hit.

Comment: @JimBalter: Precedence was my edit. OP used the term "preference".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An operator precedence table would show that a `->` binds more tightly than the cast.

```
typedef void *typeA;
typeB b;
typeA a = &b;
(typeB *)a->i;   /* wrong: attempt to dereference a void pointer */
((typeB *)a)->i; /* ok */
```

A complete operator precedence table for your future reference is provided below. In the table, operators higher in the list bind more tightly than operators lower in the list (so the Primary Expression Operators bind the most tightly). If operators of the same precedence are used in the same expression in an ambiguous way (that is, not captured within a Primary Expression Operator like `()` or `[]`), then it is resolved by following the associativity direction. So, for example the expression:

```
7 + (3 - 5 * 2 + 15) - 6
```

is evaluated in this order (according to the table):

```
7 + (3 - 10 + 15) - 6     // evaluate * in ()
7 + (-7 + 15) - 6         // evaluate - in () (it is left of the +)
7 + 8 - 6                 // evaluate + in ()
15 - 6                    // evaluate + (it is left of the -)
9                         // evaluate -
```

Of course, the compiler is free to perform the computation differently, but its result must match the result obtained when following the precedence rules.

```
Operator Type   Operator(s)                                     Associativity
=============   ===========                                     =============
Primary         () [] . -> expr++ expr--                        left-to-right
Expression 
Operators       
-------------   -----------                                     -------------
Unary           * & + - ! ~ ++expr --expr (typecast) sizeof     right-to-left
Operators       
-------------   -----------                                     -------------
Binary          * / %                                           left-to-right
Operators       + -
                >> <<
                < > <= >=
                == !=
                &
                ^
                |
                &&
                ||
-------------   -----------                                     -------------
Ternary         ?:                                              right-to-left
Operator
-------------   -----------                                     -------------
Assignment      = += -= *= /= %= >>= <<= &= ^= |=               right-to-left
Operators       
-------------   -----------                                     -------------
Comma           ,                                               left-to-right
=============   ===========                                     =============
```

Answer (score 1):

in C, -> operatior's precedence is higher than cast , which is (type name)

so (typeB *)p->i  is (typeB *)(p->i)