# Operator precedence table for the C programming language

Tags: c, operator-precedence, c11

What would a correct operator precedence table that lists all operators in the C language look like?

I have made extensive searches on the web, and found many such precedence tables. Alas, I haven't found a single one filling these requirements:

- Lists *all* operators in the C language as defined in ISO 9899:2011, without mixing in any C++ operators.
- Lists the operators in the *complete and correct* priority order.

Comment: Operator precedence in C is specified by the order the various operator groups appear in the standard (chapter 6.5). This is tedious reading, a "precedence table" that quickly sums up all operators would be preferable, particularly as reference for programming discussions on SO. If we could make such a post and use as a C FAQ, that would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precedence between member access from a pointer and cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077628/precedence-between-member-access-from-a-pointer-and-cast)

Comment: The table entry with operators of the "same" priority should also explain the precedence is based on left to right or right to left as they appear on the source line. So a total ordering the way you have specified is not possible, because for operators of the same precedence, the priority of one over the other is "it depends".

Comment: @Jxh That's not a duplicate. I have explicitly asked for C11 and tagged the post C11. Also, that answer is just a generalization that mixes up the various detailed categories from the standard into some home-brewed groups.

Comment: @jxh As for ordering in the individual groups, indeed it is per syntax. But all postfix operators have higher precedence than all prefix ones, and so on.

Comment: Hmm..., you're right. You want a table organized exactly as the C11 grammar organizes the operators?

Comment: @jxh Yes, since that is what dictates their priority. But I'd also like one which contains `_Alignof` and other such C11 news. (Maybe that one is the only new operator in C11?)

Comment: @Lundin: Actually, operator precedence in specified in C by the grammar. The order they appear in the standard is informative, not normative.

Comment: @Lundin: C11 Annex A.2.1 contains the grammar summary for expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C11 6.5/3: `"The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.85)"` and then note 85) (which in itself is informative): `"The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first."`.

Comment: @Lundin: That is consistent with what I wrote.

Comment: @jxh But that (informative) annex merely repeats what was stated in the (normative) chapter 6.5? Without any explaining text in between.

Comment: An operator precedence table wouldn't have any explaining text either.

Comment: @jxh What I meant is that the syntax in the Annex is still 3 pages long and not really a handy quick reference such, as the usual "precedence tables".

Comment: @Lundin: I agree the information could be made even more compact, but I'm sure you could type it into a table as well as anyone else could. And if you do it, it will be in a layout that you would definitely find acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

---

**Explanation**

*Prec.* denotes *operator precedence*, where group 1 has the highest precedence and group 17 the lowest.

*Assoc.* denotes [*operator associativity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), where such is applicable. Associativity can be either left-to-right or right-to-left.

**Sources**

My ambition with this post is to provide a operator precedence table on-site at Stack Overflow, which is correct and canonical. This operator precedence table corresponds directly to chapter 6.5 of ISO 9899:2011, where we can read (6.5/3):

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax. 85)

And then as a comment, in the informative (not normative) foot note:

> 85) The syntax specifies the precedence of operators in the evaluation of an expression, which is the same as the order of the major subclauses of this subclause, highest precedence first. /--/
>
> Within each major subclause, the operators have the same precedence. Left- or right-associativity is indicated in each subclause by the syntax for the expressions discussed therein.

All formal operator names from the table are taken from chapter 6.5, where such a name could be found in normative text. Informal names were included in the cases where the programmer community might be more familiar with another name than the one given in the standard.

Comment: I hoped to make this post into a wiki format, but I didn't manage to post a text table which can be edited by others. Any proofreading or corrections are highly appreciated, please leave a comment below. Preferably with a reference to the standard. As for now, the table exists in tabbed text MS Excel format on my computer. I can provide the file, if some web wizard could manage to post a HTML version of it on SO. If the table could be edited by everyone, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

http://basen.oru.se/c/operators.html

(I added **_Alignof**, which I think is the only new operator in C11, to my own table, and published it there. Maybe that's cheating? Comments and suggestions on how to improve the table are welcome.)

Comment: I assume that the first `()` is a regular parenthesis? It would then be part of the category "primary expressions" with higher priority than postfix. Or if it is a function call, it should remain where it is. The postfix category is missing the compound literal operator.

Comment: No, the first pair of parentheses is the function call operator. Regular parentheses for grouping sub-expressions are not an operator, so they are not in the table. Compound literals I don't think involve an operator at all, they're just part of the syntax, but I need to check that.

Comment: I did just cross-check your table with the standard and commented on what I could find. Compound literals are regarded as operators, C11 6.5.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a pretty great precedence table:

http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: @Lundin I was not aware that operator precedence changed in C11, and I would not believe it without proof. So, what do you say they changed to make this table invalid? Btw, I always look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: I think there were a few new operators added in C11 (`alignof`, for example), so I think he just wants to know how they fit in with the rest of the operators.