# C++ Strange behaviour for comparison with XOR value

Tags: c++, c, file

Let's take the following program (called `charco.cpp` and intentionally starts with `//`):

```
//
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("charco.cpp", "rt");
    char c = fgetc(fp);
    if(c == '/')
    {
        char c2 = fgetc(fp);
        if(c2 == 122^85) // *** OK
        {
            c2 = fgetc(fp);
            while(c2 != 246^252)  // **** NOT OK
            {
                c2 = fgetc(fp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In its current incarnation it will loop forever in the line indicated with `**** NOT OK`, because it will fail to match the endline character after the `//` so it reads the entire file...

However, if I change `246 ^ 252` to `10`, `(char)(246 ^ 252)` or just simply `'\n'` it does not loop forever anymore, it matches correctly, but `(char)246^252` fails again.

Can anyone explain me why is this strange behaviour? (compiler: g++ 4.9.2)

Comment: Aside from the iostream include, this is C.

Comment: Why is this C++ question tagged [tag:c]?

Comment: Why is this C question said to be C++?

Comment: @Borgleader: [If he's compiling it with a C++ compiler, it's C++](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281387/560648). Not very good C++, but C++.

Comment: @fritzone: What on earth are you trying to do? Can you abstract away all this "reading self into a `FILE`" gubbins and just show us some inputs and outputs to the XOR operator that you think are wrong?

Comment: Agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit.  Just capture the value of `c2`, and then construct a test case around that.

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an ***`int`***. Also note that the mode `"rt"` argument to [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) is non-standard.

Comment: reading "self" is just that everyone has a "file", it could be basically every source file

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Remember that game for children with different shaped holes? What you said basically amounts to: "If the square fits in the circular hole, it's a circle."

Comment: @ScottStensland What do you mean "raising"? That's the xor operator.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : That's where I think the problem is ... I just can't nail it down right now ...

Comment: Is this a 64-bit compile?

Comment: I reference this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence when I have doubts about precedence (or just include the parens to be safe.)

Comment: == has higher operator precedence than ^, simple as that. `(c2 == 122) ^ 85` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Borgleader: Not really.

Comment: @legends2k eh? XOR, right?

Comment: When working with XOR, I prefer to use hexadecimal literals (instead of decimal literals). It makes it easy to visualize the bit pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
while (c2 != 246^252)
```

You are doing:

```
while ((c2 != 246)^252) // Fail, bool^252
```

if c2 != 246, this will give 253 (0^252). Otherwise will give 252.

You have to use parenthesis :-)

```
while (c2 != (246^252)) // Correct, c2 != 10
```

Comment: For reference (to the OP) see e.g. [this operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: [Here's an attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table) I once made of a C11 precedence table.

Comment: Yup ... This also explain why `(c2 == 122^85)` although that it gives a very weird value is executed correctly ...

Comment: @Lundin I'll print it and stick it on the wall as reminder of this day .. and actually I have looked at the operator precedence table ... just didn't spot the spot :(

Comment: @fritzone Only true C nerds know the operator precedence of every single operator in the language :) Which is why an extra parenthesis is always encouraged as good programming practice. Even if _you_ know the operator precedence of some particular operators, the person reading your code may not. Even the creator of the C language [recognized early on](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html) that the operator precedence of == would be a cause of trouble. It is kind of a design flaw of C.

Answer (score 5):

[For historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685140/650405), the bitwise operators have a weird [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

You have to use parentheses to enforce the correct order:

```
while (c2 != (246^252))
```

In fact, I strongly recommend using parentheses all the time when you use these operators.

Here's a minimal example to show the difference:

```
cout << (1 == 1 ^ 2) << " " << (1 == (1 ^ 2)); 
// 3 0
```

Comment: I'd like to see those historical reasons :)

Comment: I'm just trying to find a good article.. basically initially the bitwise operators were used for logic operators and the actual logical operators were added later to the language, but by that time they wouldn't want to fix the precedence - too much code was relying on the precedence order.