# Postfix before prefix?

Tags: c, operators

I have read in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table) that postfix(es) are prior to prefix(es).

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
printf("%d\n",a++);
printf("%d\n",++b);
```

But this code output would be 5,6. how does this make sense then?

Comment: Operator precedence doesn't even come into it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is talked about in your links is operator precedence. That does not affect the working of the post increment. The post increment operator increases the value after the expression in calculated.

> Post-increment operator is used to increment the value of variable as
>   soon as after executing expression completely in which post increment
>   is used.

What this means is that even if you have a statement like

```
int i = 0 , j = 5 , k ;
k = ++i + j++ ;
```

The `++i` will be calculated ( `i` becomes 1 ) and the expression is calculated, and thus `k` gets the value `6` , and after assigning the value `6` to `k`, the effect of `j++` comes into place and `j` becomes `6`.

> Operator precedence determines how operators are grouped, when
>   different operators appear close by in one expression. For example, '
>   * ' has higher precedence than ' + '. Thus, the expression a + b * c means to multiply b and c , and then add a to the product (i.e., a +
>   (b * c) ).

But the precedence does not change the working of the postfix increment. It will increase the value only after the expression is calculated ( that part is independent of it's precedence ) .

I'll give you a simple example ( Hope you know about using pointers )

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
    int a[] = { 11, 22 };
    int x;
    int *p = a;
    x = *p++;
    printf( " *p = %d\n",*p );
    printf( " x = %d",x );
  }
```

The output for this is

```
 *p = 22
 x = 11
```

You can refer this [ideone](https://ideone.com/bM1DV5) link for proof.

Now lets explain that. The `++` has a higher precedence than `*` , so that code will be same as

```
x = * ( p++ );
```

That is, `++` will will make the pointer `p` point to the next address of the array , but that part is done only after the expression is calculated ( in other words, after the value of `*p` is assigned to `x` ) . So after the expression, `p` will point to the next address, which would have the value `22` while `x` will still get the value `11`.

Hope this makes it clear ( this example might be a bit hard to understand, but it's one of the best to understand this )