# Unexpected Ternary Assignation

Tags: c, variables, output, addition, ternary

```
int var = (1 == 1) ? (5) : (10);
```

This outputs `5`, which is correct.

```
int var = 100 + (1 == 1) ? (5) : (10);
```

this again outputs `5`. Why?

---

I know I can fix the problem with adding braces around the entire ternary statement, but that doesn't explain what happens with the addition and why it behaves like that on a first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator precedence table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table)

Comment: Here it's a bit more complicated. It wouldn't be the same if it wasn't the condition involved. EDIT: What ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is rules of operator precedence and that any non-zero value tests as true.

`100 + (1 == 1) ? (5) : (10)` is equivalent to `(100 + (1 == 1)) ? (5) : (10)` i.e.  `(101 != 0) ? (5) : (10)`.

Operator `?:` has lower precedence than addition.

Answer (score 4):

In C every non-zero value is “true”, here the value of `100 + (1 == 1)` is `101`, which is also “true”, therefore `(5)` is selected. Since `?:` has a very low precedence, the parentheses should be `((1==1) ? 5 : 10)` to have the effect you want.