# Why is this output of this basic C program?

Tags: c

Let me be judged as a Noob in programming, I have been learning obfuscated way of programming in c/c++, as the c compiler compiles a statement from the right hand side towards the left hand side.

I have the following code:

```
int main(){
    int x=5, y=20, z=1;
    int k = x > y < z;
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output returned is `1`, Does this means that
`x > y < z` = `(x>y) < z`
or 
`x > y < z` = `x > (y<z)`

I would love if someone would give me link to work on these skills.
Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag. There's no such language as C/C++. In this particular case, that is especially important because C++ would make `(x>y)` a `bool` whereas C makes it an `int`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/ - at the bottom there you have a useful table containing all you need to know about the operators. Play around with the example you have, it's not that hard. ;)

Comment: Change `z=-1` or `x=0` and find out. Also change `int main()` to the more correct `int main ( void )`

Comment: Does 'x > y < z' look clear to you?  If not, your code is rubbish and you should be ashamed of posting it here.  If it does look clear, I just hope that I never have to maintain any of your stuff:(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP specifically admits that the cod eis obfuscated and so of negative usefulness to future visitors to SO.  Also, it's garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C grammar (6.5.8 Relational operators)

```
1 relational-expression:
    shift-expression
    relational-expression < shift-expression
    relational-expression > shift-expression
    relational-expression <= shift-expression
    relational-expression >= shift-expression
```

> 1 The relational operators group **left-to-right** (C++ Standard :) )

And

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.107) The result has
>   type int.

Thus the initializer in this declaration

```
int k =x>y<z;
```

is equivalent to

```
int k = ( x > y ) < z;
```

As x is less than y then expression `x > y` yields 0 and as z is greater than 0 then the full expression yields 1.

The following operators have right-to-left-grouping:

```
unary operators 
conditional operator  
assignmnet and compound assignment operators
```

Comment: While this is certainly a correct answer, I would not recommend beginner programmers to go look for operator precedence in the standard, as the standard is quite confusing to read when it comes to determining precedence (it is determined by the order of appearance of operator group sub chapters of chapter 6.5).

Comment: @Lundin What is not clear for you in the quotes I showed?

Comment: This specific case is clear, but what about the next time he wonders about operator precedence of some other operator?

Comment: @Lundin  What about tomorrow will be the end of the world?

Comment: The aim of SO is to provide answers not only to the OP, but to future readers. Constantly giving people fish is fine as far as SO policies go, but it is better to teach them how to fish.

Comment: @Lundin  The question is not about precedence of operators in C. The question about relational operators and their grouping. Of course you may write about for example virtual destructors because tomorrow the author will want to know about virtual destructors.:)

Comment: @Lundin  You have a rich imagination.:)

Comment: In comment on the above question @Msalters state that the c++ lang. would have returned a `bool` value but when I compiled it using gcc there is no warning related to type-casting,is it ignored by the compiler?

Comment: @MaMba  C has no boolean type. It has type _Bool but it is an integer type. So in C the result has type int but in C++ the result has type bool.

Answer (score 4):

Change `z=-1` or `x=0` and find out. Also change `int main()` to the more correct `int main ( void )`

Changing `z = -1` will ouput `0`, whereas `k`  will be `1` if you assign it `x > y == z` if `z = 0`. So in short:

```
k = x > y < z;
```

is the same as writing

```
k = (x > y) < z;
```

left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check operator precedence, which is easiest by looking at an [operator precedence table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140394/584518). If such a table is decent, it will list the operators > and < in a group called *relational operators*. All operators in this group have the same operator precedence.

Since the operators > and < have the same precedence, the order in which the operands will get processed is determined by the associativity of that group of operators. For the relational operators, this is left-to-right. Therefore the expression is guaranteed to be processed as `(x > y) < z`

Comment: That table is superb,can't up-vote your answer I don't have that much rep,I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MaMba The table has only been proof-read by me and one C guru, so take it for what it is worth. I wish I could post a formatted table on SO in such a way that it could be maintainable by others, but I never figured out how to do that. If anyone has a clue about how to do that, I'd be happy to turn the post into a community wiki.

Comment: the table contents are fixed,then what is the need of it bieng maintained?

Comment: @MaMba Well, if there's some error in it and it needs to be fixed, none but me can do so... which is not really ideal for the SO format. Also looks like I had to fiddle around with resolution to be able to post it, the image quality isn't the best.

Answer (score 0):

In C the boolean values are numerical values, so:

false -> 0
true  -> != 0, hence any number that is not 0 will represent the boolean true.

So in case of your code:

```
int k = x > y < z;
```

can be split in the following way:

```
int k = (x > y) < z;
```

that will be:

```
int k = ( 5 > 20) < 1;
```

the first part evaluates to false (0 that is) then the equality will loook this way:

```
int k = 0 < 1;
```

which is true, hence

int k = 1;

Answer (score 0):

k = ( 5 > 20 ) < 1= False (0)

k = (0 < 1) = True (1)

printf (%d, k) = 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should know the `Operator precedence and associativity`. You can google or see the book `<<c++ primer>>`. First the operator `>` and `<` have a same precedence. Then we should use the `associativity`, there the operator only have `left associativity`. So the answer is `x> y< z= (x>y)<z)`. I hope this can help you. `Remember: 1. precedence; 2. associativity.`