# What does the (1u<<x<<y) mean?

Tags: c

I have a problem,

```
1U << 0 = 1

1U << 1 = 2

1U << 2 = 4
```

etc... okey..

for example ;

```
1u<<1<<2
```

Can you tell me this mean ?

Comment: Why don't you *try* it? Make a small program that prints out the result.

Comment: i tried it                                                                                                                   #define LED_RED (1U<<1) ..........                                                                                                                                                           *((unsigned int volatile *)(0x40025000+(LED_BLUE<<2))=LED_BLUE;  but ı dont understand it

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. What **specifically** about the descriptions on the various pages you will find by a simple search for the `<<` operator is unclear? What else did you try to answer the question yourself?

Comment: A idio(ma)tic instruction. Better use parentesis when you deal with bitshifts. Much better, unless you do not remember each precedence and associativity of the operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `<<`<sup>1</sup> is left associative<sup>2</sup> this is 
    `1U<<1<<2 = 2<<2 = 8U`

<sub>1: Biwise shift left</sub>
<sub>2:  *associativity* indicates in what order operators of equal precedence in an expression are applied.</sub>
<sub>**Note: The result of a bit shift operation on a signed argument gives implementation-defined results, so in theory `1U<<x` is more portable than `1<<x`**</sub>

Comment: Correction: it is `32U`, not `32`!

Comment: Yes, that's why I use parentheses (and spaces) for such expressions. You still should get the signed-ness of the terms correct.

Comment: #define LED_RED (1U<<1) ..........                                                                                                                                                           *((unsigned int volatile *)(0x40025000+(LED_BLUE<<2));   so, because of 2^3 ,   LED _RED value is 0000 0001 and 
If this value is <<2 , the final result is  0x40025008 ,, is it right ?   i think that is right :)

Answer (score 2):

The *operator precedence rules* dictate how a C expression with multiple operands on the same line is parsed. This is a muddy part of the C language, so an [operator precedence table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140394/584518) is a useful tool for understanding.

In this case there are two `<<` operators with the same precedence, so the *operator associativity* of that group of operands then dictates how the expression is parsed. It is left-to-right for the shift operators, meaning that the expression is guaranteed to be parsed as `(1u<<1)<<2`.

In other words, it is exactly the same thing as writing `1u << 3`.

The `u` suffix guarantees that the integer constant 1 is of unsigned type. Had we just typed `1`, this integer constant 1 would be of type `int` which is `signed`. That would have been bad, because performing shift operations on signed integer types can invoke all kinds of undefined behavior (bugs) and should therefore always be avoided. For example `1 << 31` is a severe bug on a 32 bit system, whereas `1u << 31` is perfectly fine and safe.