# C Program to read number character by character giving incorrect result

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int peekchar() {
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    if (c != EOF) {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
    }   
    return c;
}

int readNumber(void) {
    int c;
    int accumulator = 0;
    while ((c = peekchar() != EOF) && isdigit(c)) {
       c = getchar();
       accumulator *= 10; 
       accumulator += c - '0';
    }   
    return accumulator;
}

int main() {
    int result = readNumber();
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read an integer written in decimal notation from stdin until the first non-digit. But its not giving the correct result:

```
M1508444:CProg sb054043$ gcc -g3 readNumber.c -o readNumber
M1508444:CProg sb054043$ ./readNumber 
123
0
```

Can someone please help me identify the problem?

Comment: [so]: [Operator precedence table for the C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table-for-the-c-programming-language)

Comment: The root cause of your problem is that `while ((c = peekchar() != EOF) && isdigit(c))` is a **horrible** style to use for writing code.  *Why* did you try to stuff all that into one line of code?  What did you gain from writing code like that, other than code so broken it was beyond your ability to find the problem?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Although, that said, this is idiomatic C (without the parentheses slip) so should be readable. In this case though the expression further simplifies.

Comment: @Bathsheba OK, that makes it a bug-prone idiom that's especially hard for inexperienced coders to debug because there's too much going on.  Again, what's the gain over using more than one line?  I've seen references to "brevity of code", as if that's a goal in and of itself.  I'm of the opinion that anyone who cites "brevity of code" as a goal hasn't really thought things out, nor ever been responsible for fixing bugs that pop up at 2 am and 2,000 miles away.  I prefer to write code in a style that actually helps to prevent the introduction of bugs such as the one here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with operator precedence. `c = peekchar() != EOF` is grouped as `c = (peekchar() != EOF)`, and so `c` is either `0` or `1`, which accounts for the result.

Fix with `(c = peekchar()) != EOF`.

Or, given that `isdigit` is defined to be 0 for `EOF`, your loop conditional can be simplified to

```
while (isdigit(c = peekchar())){
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to modify your while loop like below:-

```
 while ( (c = peekchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c)) {
   c = getchar();
   accumulator *= 10; 
   accumulator += c - '0';
}
```

First of all you need to read the value and store it in variable `c` and that you can achieve by doing `(c = peekchar())`. Once the value stored in `c` now your `while loop` will first check whether it is `EOF` if not then only it will check whether it is a digit or not.