# Could anybody explain how "if" statement executed here

Tags: c

According to my limited knowledge logical operators have left-right order of evaluation. By that rule it should evaluate **x && y** which is **1** and then it should evaluate **== 1** in the if statement. But that is what not happening. Could anyone help me with this.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    if (x && y == 1)
        printf("true\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");
}
```

Comment: its clearly show that if(x and y both are equals to 1){true}else{false}

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: The variable `y` is not equal to 1 :)

Comment: @Waleed no, that is not what that code means.

Comment: _Order of evaluation_ and _operator precedence_ are two different, although related things. Don't mix them up! The former describes the order in which the code is executed, the latter the order that the code is read by the compiler.

Comment: See [Operator precedence table for the C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table-for-the-c-programming-language).  This might even be considered a duplicate of that question by some.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Eh, that particular link I'm not too proud of. The intention was to include a correct table on SO, but I never quite managed to get all the HTML right. That way the table could have been maintained. It was written by me and might have errors.

Comment: @Lundin Still, that's an admirable effort.  And quite relevant here, I'd think.

Comment: Well, the most important thing is that people don't read the original table posted in K&R, because that one is incorrect.

Comment: I got this concept, thank you for responding so quick and overwhelmingly, I love stack overflow now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [order of operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is different than what you think.

Your expression is equivalent to

```
x && (y==1)
```

which is `false` in your case.

Comment: How should I decide where to put () parentheses. Like in this example int z = x << 1 > 5;

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. You can always add unneeded parentheses, but when in doubt, just write two separate statements. Everyone will be much happier (someone else reading your code, or you reading your code in a year's time).

Comment: I'm not writing these. These are the questions I'm facing while solving c language quiz.

Comment: Well, then you'll need to look at the table on the page I linked to. The first operator you hit is evaluated first. So replace the operator expression by its result and go through the table again.

Comment: Oh, finally got it. It was not as simple as I thought it. You were great help @rubenvb, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to accept the answer you feel best answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

**try this.**

because of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    if ((x && y) == 1)
        printf("true\n");
else
    printf("false\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try not to think about order of evaluation too much.  It will often confuse you.  The more important things to focus on is how the operators are grouped together and what the expression *means*.

The `&&` operator has relatively low *precedence*.  Almost any time you use it, it will have the form

```
if( condition_1 && condition_b )
```

and the interpretation is the obvious: "if `condition_a` is true *and* `condition_b` is true".

In your case, `condition_a` is just `x`, and `condition_b` is `y == 1`.  So the interpretation is "if `x` is true *and* `y` equals 1".

What does it mean for `x` to be true?  Simply that it's not zero.  So we could expand this further: it's as if you had written

```
if ( x != 0 && y == 1 )
```

and the interpretation is "if `x` is not equal to 0 *and* `y` is equal to 1".

Remember, precedence says how the operators are grouped together.  In your case, it's as if you had written

```
if ( x && ( y == 1 ) )
```

The `== 1` part goes with the `y`.  `==` binds more tightly than `&&`.

In terms of "order of evaluation", you can say that, yes, the compiler emits code that figures out whether `x` is true, and code that figures out whether `y` is equal to 1, before it uses `&&` to determine whether they're both true.  In the case of `&&`, we also know that it will decide whether `x` is true *before* it decides whether `y` is equal to 1.  (But this is a rather special property of the `&&` and `||` operators.  It does *not* apply to most of the rest of the more ordinary operators like `+` and `/`.)

Answer (score 0):

Because `y == 1` is false as `y = 2`, written before `if` statement.

It does not evaluate they way you think. It evaluates `x` and then `y == 1` and then `&&`, which is in your case in `1 && 0` and you have `false` result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).
Because of *operator precedence* the expression `if (x && y == 1)` results in `if (x && (y == 1))`.
So, the whole expression results to `false` because `y==1` is `false`.

Use parenthesis and change it to `if ((x && y) == 1)` to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
if (x && y == 1)
```

above statement is equivalent to

```
if(x && (y==1) ) /* y==1 performed first, which is false */
```

As you can see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

You want to get `true` as output, then first perform `x&&y` by keeping `()`.

```
if ( (x && y) == 1) { /* now () has higher precedence, so it perform x&&y first which results in true(1) and then 1==1 results in true */
}
else {
}
```