# Operator precedence and order of evaluation for complex expression

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I was looking at the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(uint32_t *pVal)
{
  uint32_t i = 8;

  *pVal = i *= 10;
}
```

At the first glance it is clear that before returning from `foo()`, `*pVal` would be 80 as well as the value of `i`. And this is indeed what happens according to [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/elQqfE):

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], 8
        imul    eax, dword ptr [rbp - 12], 10
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], eax
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

However after checking the operator precedence from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the precedence of `=` is higher than the precedence of `*=`, so it seems that the value of `*pVal` should be 8 and the value of `i` should be 80...

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**:

In addition to the great answer by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene), there is also a nice [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: Please note that the linked precedence table has errors (they put cast operator in the wrong group, there are 17 groups not 15 etc). Most such tables have errors, since the C standard doesn't list such a table. At one point I got sick of all these bad tables and attempted to made one myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table-for-the-c-programming-language). However, the formatting is icky since it is a screen shot :/

Comment: @Lundin I'd say your table is wrong because it puts casts in the wrong group. Casts are unary (prefix) operators, and you cannot have prefix operators with different precedence levels. Also, primary expressions are not operators.

Comment: @melpomene Unary operators and casts are in different groups in standard (grouping specified in C17 draft 6.5 p3), with casts having lower precedence.

Comment: @melpomene The C standard C17 6.5.4 is the group with cast operators (there's just one). Which as indicated by the syntax has lower precedence than unary operators. My table follows the standard groups and syntax, unlike the one at cppreference.

Comment: @Lundin I see `cast-expression: unary-expression | ...` and `unary-expression: unary-operator cast-expression | ...`, so they're mutually recursive and neither has higher precedence than the other. The only reason they're in different groups is a sort of grammar hack to remove ambiguity with `sizeof`: According to the grammar, `sizeof (int) + 0` parses unambiguously as `(sizeof (int)) + 0`, not `sizeof ((int)+0)` (i.e. there is no cast in this expression).

Comment: @melpomene The whole chapter 6.5 syntax is built so that each operator lists the one with higher precedence before the operators of its own group. You'll find `multiplicative-expression: cast-expression ...` next in line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table you linked to shows all assignment operators (including `=` and `*=`) at the same precedence level: 14.

They're also right associative, so `x = y *= z` parses as `x = (y *= z)`, as expected.

---

If `=` had a higher precedence than `*=`, then `x = y *= z` would parse as `(x = y) *= z`, which would be a hard error because `=` doesn't yield an lvalue (you cannot assign to the result of an assignment). If `=` did return its left operand as an lvalue, then `(x = y) *= z` would have undefined behavior because it's modifying `x` twice without an intervening sequence point. And if there were a sequence point after the inner assignment, the final values of the variables after `(*pVal = i) *= 10` would be `i = 8` (unmodified) and `*pVal = 80`.

[Live demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@0OFWhuKQoM7nEmgvELk8sysvMSy@25uLKrVRQKUvMUbBVMLAGcwrCwLwYkChEJBPItQAq1VCBSapkaipo2SoYArUUFGXmlSgoZYJFrRVgCsAqY/KUrP//BwA) (using Perl, which has a `=` that returns an lvalue as described above)

Comment: @AlexLop. It also says the first column is *Precedence*. All lines within the same row of the table have the same precedence.

Comment: @AlexLop. It's the "Precedence" column that's listed from top to bottom, with `1` being the highest and `15` being the lowest. All operators on the same level have the same precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am glad that I just misunderstood the chart.