# What does ++cc[c] do in The C Programming Language(Second Edition) Exercise 1-14's Histogram's Function?

Tags: c

I have some trouble to understand the actual function of `++cc[c]` in the histogram do,the code is shown below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXHIST 15
#define MAXCHAR 128

/*print horizontal histogram freq. of different char*/
int main()
{
    int c, i;
    int len;
    int maxvalue;
    int cc[MAXCHAR];

    for (i = 0; i < MAXCHAR; ++i)
        cc[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c < MAXCHAR)
            ++cc[c];
    maxvalue = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < MAXCHAR; ++i)
        if( cc[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = cc[i];

    for (i = 1; i < MAXCHAR; ++i) {
        if (isprint(i))
            printf("%5d - %c - %5d : ", i, i, cc[i]);
        else
            printf("%5d -   - %5d : ", i, cc[i]);
        if (cc[i] > 0) {
            if ((len = cc[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
                len = 1;
        } else
            len = 0;
        while (len > 0) {
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

I understand how `cc[i] = 0` work however I do not know what is the function of `++cc[c]` do and how it interact with `cc[i]`.

Comment: `++cc[c]` is almost (but not quite) the same as `cc[c] = cc[c] + 1`. It tells the code here that one more of the inputted character was seen. `++` here is called ["pre-increment operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

Comment: It is the same as `cc[c] = cc[c] + 1;`

Comment: Bookmark [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: So it increments numerical value to `cc[c]` and it does affect the value of `cc[i]`, right?

Comment: It's crazy how much time is wasted by programmers who have too much pride to use parentheses. Or perhaps this is meant to be an exercise to learn operator precedence. Who knows?

Comment: Side note: `putchar('/n');` should be `putchar('\n');`

Comment: @Spikatrix I changed the code in the question because it was just a transcription error on op's behalf.

Comment: You're missing braces from the outer for loop too!

Answer (score 2):

The [operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140394/918959) tells that brackets `[]` are applied first, followed then by the increment operator `++` used as a prefix, i.e. `++cc[c]` is parsed as `++(cc[c])`.

Indeed in this context I would have preferred the use of `cc[c]++;` as it will be easy to parse without ambiguity even without knowing the precedence.

What `cc[c]++` or `++cc[c]` do is to increment the `c`th item in the array pointed to by `cc` by one. The two forms differ in the *value of the expression*, the former evaluating to the value *before* increment, and the latter to the value *after* increment. The value of the expression is *ignored* here as it is evaluated as a `void` expression in the expression statement, and so you can use either form.

---

The first `for` loop using `i` zeroes each element in the array of character counts (`cc`). That loop is not actually needed if the array is zero-initialized: just writing

```
int cc[MAXCHAR] = {0};
```

will set to zero each and every element in the `cc` array.

Comment: Thanks for you ans. Since `cc[c]` had been incremented, will it affect the value of `cc[i]`?

Comment: @littleclover If `c` is equal to `i`, then yes. Else it won't affect it

Comment: @littleclover it won't ever affect `cc[i]` in that code because `i` will be *128* by the time loop ends and the last valid index will be `127`.