i*=j ==x and i=i*j ==x behaving differently in C
I have these two code snippets that are acting differently:
int i=2,j=3;
if (j*=i == 2){
    printf("yes, i= %d, j= %d",i,j);
} else {
    printf("no, i= %d, j= %d",i,j);
}

int i=2,j=3;
if (j=j*i == 2){
    printf("yes, i= %d, j= %d",i,j);
} else {
    printf("no, i= %d, j= %d",i,j);
}

I assume that the right operand is being compared with 2 first, ie j*=(i==2) and j=(j*i==2) respectively, where the first returns 1 and multiplies it with j resulting in the output yes, i= 2, j= 3, and the second returns 0 and multiplies it resulting in no, i= 2, j= 0.
My question is why is *=i different from =j*i? Does the compiler just take the right operand immediately because comparison has a higher precedence?

When it comes to operator precedence rules, parenthesis are your friends and helpers in obtaining the result that you want. Better to use parenthesis to insist on a particular series of computations rather than assuming that you remember all of the rules.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table-for-the-c-programming-language

If you already know about precedence, you can easily look up the table and find that the compound operators have a very low precedence. That is basically the same as putting everything on the right side into brackets before applying the operator. Just as low as the assignment operator as well.

@RichardChambers, I'm new to C so I'm just experimenting. I had figured it out with parentheses and was just trying to wrap my head around it.

@AviBerger, you are correct, I have changed the title. Thanks

My rule for parentheses is if I have to look up the precedence, I use parentheses. They're free, don't feel like you need to hold back.

@tariqalr I understand that you are trying to understand the precedence rules. C is such a simple language yet that very simplicity has a great deal of flexibility. There are also a lot of gray areas that lead to Undefined Behavior so using precision with the language is important. One reason for not relying on rules is that most people are only going to know the main rules. Writing source is also about writing for programmers who will be reading it.

As you've figured out, the multiplication operator * has higher precedence than the equality operator ==, which in turn has higher precedence than the assignment operators = and *=.
So this:
if (j*=i == 2){

Is the same as this:
if (j*=(i == 2)){

And this:
if (j=j*i == 2){

Is the same as this:
if (j=((j*i) == 2)){

You would get the same result using = and *= if you used parenthesis like this:
if ((j*=i) == 2){
...
if ((j=j*i) == 2){


Thank you, somehow I didn't wrap my head around the fact that *= is an operator in and of itself, and isn't treated similarly to macros where it's changed to =op1 * op2.

@tariqalr Some macro #define MUL(op1, op2) (op1 = op1 * op2) is different than compound assignment *=, because *= guarantees to only evaluate op1 once. Consider for example this: https://godbolt.org/z/rK4z1eerE

Due to the operator precedence expressions in these if statements
if (j*=i == 2){

and
if (j=j*i == 2){

may be equivalently rewritten using parentheses the following way
if ( j *= ( i == 2 ) ){

and
if ( j = ( ( j * i ) == 2 ) ){

As it is seen sub-expressions with the equality operator
i == 2

and
( j * i ) == 2

are different and yield different results.
To get the same result you need to rewrite the second if statement the following way
if ( j = j * ( i == 2 ) ){

