# Printing a string with char pointer in C

Tags: c

In case of pointers `*p` means value stored and `p` means the address (for a declaration `int *p`).
As per the below declaration, `name` points to the string "Example". So `*name` would be "E" and NOT an address, but an actual value. So how does the program below work? I mean, we are incrementing the value itself and not the pointer (confused).

```
char *name="Example";
while(*name !='\0'){
    printf("%c\n",*name++);
}
```

**Prints**

```
    E
    x
    a
    m
    p
    l
    e
```

Comment: operator precedence

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: "name points to the string "Example"" - No. `name` points to the first `char` of the array. C does not have a string type. Other assumptions of your's are also not correct (or badly formatted - use markdown!)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Please don't link C++ sites for C questions!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077660/315052

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Olaf the question had a C++ tag at the time I posted that comment.

Comment: `*name` is 'E' (a `char` value), not `"E"` (a string). But @Olaf, a *pointer to a string* is by definition a pointer to its initial character (C11 7.1.1p1).

Comment: `name` points to a single character *at a time*. By incrementing it, successive values of `name` point to successive `char` elements of the string.

Comment: @KeithThompson So if I use " instead of ' does C treats them differently? I mean apart from string or char

Comment: @redsoxlost: What do you mean "apart from string or char"? That *is* the difference. `'E'` is a character constant. (For historical reasons, it's of type `int` in C; in C++ it's of type `char`.) `"E"` is a string literal. It's of type `char[2]` in C, `const char[2]` in C++ (2 because of the terminating null character `'\0'`).

Comment: @redsoxlost: Yes, enclosing materials in single vs double quotes makes a lot of difference in C.  When asking questions, be very careful about which you use — the difference matters!  And I didn't enclose the "E" in the question in back-ticks because then your statement would have been definitively wrong rather than just 'mostly wrong'.  Casual use of single quotes vs double quotes is OK (up to a point) in written English; it is not OK in text discussing C.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It does not change what I wrote. And this viewpoint is way more clear and uniform than dealing with the term "string" (actually _string literal_ here). A beginner should first understand C-strings are just `char[]` with a special convention.

Comment: if you declare char *name="Example"; compiler put \0 at the end of name that indicates end of string. see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean   this is only reason that this *name !='\0' in while condition is true. In last iteration of while loop (7) after printf prints last 'e' in "Example", *name++ second part (++ increase the pointer index) and now name points to \0, and while condition is False, brakes.

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpreted the `*name++` expression: even though `++` follows `*name`, it applies to `name` alone, not `*name`, because operator `++` has higher precedence than pointer dereference operator `*`.

This rule of precedence is very commonly used in C programs. For example, K&R's one-line `strcpy` implementation uses this expression twice:

```
void strcpy( char* dest, const char *src) {
    while (*dest++ = *src++)
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The incrementing `name++` has a higher precedence than the de-referencing. `*name`.

So it's basically: `*(name++)`. As opposed to: `(*name)++`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the table at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence , postfix `++` has higer precedence than dereference `*`. So what happens is that first `name++` is evaluated which increments the pointer but returns the original address that `operator*` (dereference/indirection) is then invoked on.

So the effect is that you dereference the current value of the pointer but the pointer is subsequently incremented.