# C system calls open()

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am having trouble with `open()`. It always returns `-1` and I don't know what's wrong with the code.
It keeps saying:

> ```
> r1: No such file or directory
> ```

but the txt file is in the same directory with the C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 256

char upper(char c);

int main(void){

    int fd1, read1, fd2, write2;
    char *buffer[BUFFSIZE];

    fd1 = open("minuscole.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd1 < 0) { perror("r1"); exit(1); }
    read1 = read(fd1, buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    close(fd1);

    printf("%d", read1);
    if(fd2 = open("maiuscole.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644) > 0){
        write2 = write(fd2, buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    }
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to create a file called: `"maiuscole.txt"` and write what is in: `"minuscole.txt"`.

Comment: Check `errno` for details. This usually gives you a more concrete reason why it failed. You're supposed to test the result of `open` and act accordingly, but in this code you do a conditional `write()` yet always `close()` which might operate on an error code instead of a real file descriptor. You also mean `if ((fd = open()) > 0)` and not assigning `fd2` to be the result of the `>0` comparison which happens due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Warning: `char *buffer[BUFFSIZE]` is an array of *character pointers*, not characters.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the full file path?

Comment: You're not assigning `fd2` correctly. You're setting it to the result of `>`, not the FD returned by `open()`. You need an extra set of parentheses around the assignment.

Comment: @Barmar is right, saying:  `if ( (fd2 = open(...)) > 0)` though I recommend changing this to `>=0` because zero is a valid file descriptor.

Comment: This is not your immediate problem but the next one in line. `char *buffer[BUFFSIZE];` is wrong, you do not want an array of pointers. And the next one: do not mix `read` and `printf`, `read` does not produce a null terminated string. And the next one: don't write more characters than you have, which is exactly `read1`. And the next one: do not close what you did not open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you say your input file is co-located with your source file, that does not mean you are also running the executable from the same location. The error message clearly indicates that you are not.

To fix, determine which directory you are running your executable from, make sure your input file is located there, and that you have permission to create your output file there.

As mentioned in the comments, your assignment statement for `fd2` is incorrect, since the assignment operator has lower [precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077660/315052) than the comparison operator. For the sake of consistency, I suggest you change the code to match the style used for `fd1`. Note that `0` is also a valid file descriptor.

```
fd2 = open("maiuscole.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
if(fd2 >= 0){
    //...
```

The second argument to `read` and `write` take a `void *`/`const void *` respectively, so it masks a bug you have where you are passing a `char *[]` (which decays to a `char **`) to those functions. That is not your intention, since a `char **` can only store `sizeof(char *)` bytes. You intend to store up to `BUFFERSIZE` bytes. Change `buffer` to be an array of `char` rather than an array of `char *`.

```
char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
```

After you read the data from your input file, the return value of the `read` call is how many bytes were read. You should only write that many bytes into your output file, not the entire buffer.

```
    write2 = write(fd2, buffer, read1);
```

If there were only 10 bytes read, then the bytes after the first 10 in the buffer are uninitialized, and you should not write them into your output.

There are other cases and error checking for you to consider. I won't provide all the solutions, but you should consider that:

- Your input file may be larger than `BUFFSIZE`.
- The call to `read` may return less than `BUFFSIZE` even if the file is larger than `BUFFSIZE`.
- The call to `write` may return less than `read1`.

Finally, a note about `close`. You are not alone in ignoring the return value of `close`, it is a very common thing even in production code. However, it is still good practice to check whether or not the `close` succeeded. Under certain conditions, it may fail because the descriptor had already been closed before. You might be interested in knowing if that happens, since it indicates a logical error of some sort in the program. While closing an invalid file descriptor is benign, in the future, you might accidentally close a file descriptor that is now being used by some other part of the program.